# Vertical Scroll on Two Different Screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to vertical scroll on two different screen at the same time that if one user will scroll then the other div should automatically scroll to that position as on the first div.

Issue I'm getting is in small screen a bit space is remaining from the bottom try to see it by slow scrolling. I'm attaching code below what I tried so far

```js
var global_std = 0;
 var global_tch = 0;
 
 function function_std(){
  global_std = $(".scroll_std").scrollTop();
  $("#tch_id").scrollTop(global_std);
 }

 
 function function_tch(){
  global_tch = $(".scroll_tch").scrollTop();
  $("#std_id").scrollTop(global_tch);
 }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 .container {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
 }
 .student {
  width: 35%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 .teacher {
  width: 60%;
  height: 700px;
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 .clear {
  clear: both;
 }
 .learning-space {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
 }
 h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div id="std_id" class="student scroll_std" onscroll="function_std();">
  <h2>Student Screen</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="learning-space"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="tch_id" class="teacher scroll_tch" onscroll="function_tch();">
  <h2>Teacher Screen</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="learning-space"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bit with help of my friend and we get a perfect solution for it so I'm gonna post it in answer and it works fine for me. We modify java script and got the right solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var master = "tch_id";
    var slave = "std_id";
    var master_tmp;
    var slave_tmp;
    var timer;

    var sync = function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == slave) {
            master_tmp = master;
            slave_tmp = slave;
            master = slave;
            slave = master_tmp;
        }

        $("#" + slave).unbind("scroll");

        var ypercentage = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight);
        var xpercentage = this.scrollLeft / (this.scrollWidth - this.offsetWidth);

        var y = ypercentage * ($("#" + slave).get(0).scrollHeight - $("#" + slave).get(0).offsetHeight);
        var x = xpercentage * ($("#" + slave).get(0).scrollWidth - $("#" + slave).get(0).offsetWidth);

        $("#" + slave).scrollTop(y);
        $("#" + slave).scrollLeft(x);

        if (typeof (timer) !== 'undefind')
            clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(function () { $("#" + slave).scroll(sync) }, 200)
    }

    $('#' + master + ', #' + slave).scroll(sync);

});
```